# Drop contradicting duplicates from a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have a Pandas dataframe as following :

```
df = DataFrame({'id' : [0,1,1,2,2], 'married' : [True,True,False,False,False]})

   id married
0   0    True
1   1    True
2   1   False
3   2   False
4   2   False
```

i would like to group this dataframe by the column `id`, but also to remove the whole duplicates if the values in `married` is not the same for same value of of `id` not just taking the first row as we get from using `drop_duplicates` method.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["id"])

   id married
0   0    True
1   1    True
3   2   False
```

instead i want to have this as my result

```
   id married
0   0    True
3   2   False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.groupby` on `id` followed by [`.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas.DataFrame.filter) and then `.drop_duplicates`:

```
>>> pred = lambda obj: obj['married'].nunique() == 1
>>> df.groupby('id').filter(pred).drop_duplicates('id')
   id married
0   0    True
3   2   False
```